Parametrized moduli spaces of semistable bundles by varying Kähler classes
Inspired by Liviu Nicolaescu's answer here, I was eager on trying to come up with examples of parameter spaces $\Lambda$, configuration spaces $\mathscr{C}$ and parametrized moduli spaces $\mathscr{M}$.
What I thought of was the following. If we consider $X$ a compact Kähler manifold and $\Lambda = \mathcal{K}_X \subset H^{1,1}(X) \cap H^2(X,\Bbb R)$, the Kähler cone of $X$. Can we pick $\mathscr{C}$ to be the collection of all holomorphic vector bundles over $X$  of fixed rank and degree and consider $$\mathscr{M}=\{(E,[\omega]) \mid E\text{ is $\mu$-semistable with respect to $[\omega]$} \}.$$ Here $\mu(E)=\deg(E)/\operatorname{rk}(E)$ and $$\deg(E)=\int_X c_1(E) \wedge [\omega]^{n-1}.$$
I now quite little about the theory of moduli spaces, but this would now give for each Kähler class $[\omega]$ a space $$\mathscr{M}_{[\omega]}=\{E \mid E\text{ is $\mu$-semistable with respect to $[\omega]$} \}.$$ Are these actually moduli spaces with any sort of structure or am I just barking up the wrong tree here? It would be very nice if these guys had the structure of a smooth manifold or something.
I'm also not entirely sure on if should drop the condition of having a fixed degree on the objects of $\mathscr{C}$ while varying the Kähler classes? Cheers to anyone who can shed some light on this train of thought!
As a follow up, what if instead of the Kähler cone, we consider integral Kähler classes? Under the Kodaira embedding theorem, these would give different ample line bundles which we can use to embed $X$ into projective space.

All this has been thoroughly studied in the last 30 years. You could start with The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves by D. Huybrechts and M. Lehn.

That book does this in so general context that I have difficulties parsing the relevant information through the technicalities unfortunately. @abx
